# What happened to Update-Database -Script?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have been using (and loving) `Update-Database -Script` for some time now.  Instead of executing the Entity Framework Migration directly on the database, it creates an SQL file for you!  Then you can edit and run the SQL when you want (or give it to a DBA).

In EF Core, it appears to be missing:

```
PM> help Update-Database
Update-Database [[-Migration] <String>] [-Context <String>] [-Project <String>] [-StartupProject <String>] [<CommonParameters>]
```

Is this going to be implemented?  Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Jeez, I feel dumb now, but I'll post the answer anyway in case this helps someone.  The command has been renamed.  Now use:

```
Script-Migration
```